# Docker build fails with Error: Unable to find a match: e2fsprogs xfsprogs mdadm parted

Tags: docker, rhel

Base image is
[redhat ubi8/ubi](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/ubi8/ubi/5c359854d70cc534b3a3784e)

```
Step 5/10 : RUN yum install ca-certificates e2fsprogs xfsprogs util-linux mdadm parted lvm2 libudev-devel -y
 ---> Running in 792zfd35b185
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS  2.1 MB/s | 803 kB     00:00
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStre 5.9 MB/s | 3.0 MB     00:00
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeRea 120 kB/s |  18 kB     00:00
Package ca-certificates-2021.2.50-80.0.el8_4.noarch is already installed.
No match for argument: e2fsprogs
No match for argument: xfsprogs
Package util-linux-2.32.1-35.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
No match for argument: mdadm
No match for argument: parted
Error: Unable to find a match: e2fsprogs xfsprogs mdadm parted
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install ca-certificates e2fsprogs xfsprogs util-linux mdadm parted lvm2 libudev-devel -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Docker file is below

```
#Docker file
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi
...
...
...
RUN yum install ca-certificates e2fsprogs xfsprogs util-linux nvme-cli mdadm parted lvm2 libudev-devel -y
```

How to resolve it. I have an active subscription on my host machine

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve]?  The packages you mention here are all things that manage physical disks and filesystems; a Docker container doesn't have these things and it might work to just remove those packages from your image build.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling Docker and installing Buildah worked